# How to update database/model to allow deletion of a row that will result in the foreign key of another item becoming null

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

My application has a class called `Chemical` with a primary key called `ChemicalId`. It also has a class `SampleLocation` that has a foreign key `ChemicalId` that is tied to the `Chemical` table.

I need to be able to remove a `Chemical` from the database (delete it) and thereby set the value of `ChemicalId` in each `SampleLocation` to null. However, when I attempt to delete the `Chemical` in my application, I get the following error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.SampleLocations_dbo.Chemicals_ChemicalId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-LIMS-20160112103244", table "dbo.SampleLocations", column 'ChemicalId'.

In my database, a `SampleLocation` does not 'need' a chemical assigned to it, so nulls are ok, but if there is an id in the `ChemicalId` column, then it MUST refer to a valid `Chemical`.

The column type of `ChemicalId` is of `int?` so nulls are allowed. My class does not have the `[required]` attribute on it, so why can I not do this delete?

After searching online for the last two days, I have some inkling that I need to do something with an `OnModelCreating` method, but I have no such method in my application anywhere and every example of one I find has it in a class that inherits from a class called `DbContext`, but my app has no such class (which is a whole other line of inquiry/rabbit hole I should go down one day.) Any ideas?

My models:

**1)** SampleLocation class:

```
public class SampleLocation
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Location ID")]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(35, ErrorMessage = "The Lease Name is limited to 35 characters")]
    [Index("ix_uniqueSP", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Lease")]
    public string LeaseName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(35, ErrorMessage = "The Well Number/Name is limited to 35 characters")]
    [Index("ix_uniqueSP", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Well Name")]
    public string WellNumber { get; set; }

    //Foreign key
    [Required]
    [Index("ix_uniqueSP", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }

    //Foreign key
    [Required]
    [Index("ix_uniqueSP", 4, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "District")]
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DistrictId")]
    public virtual District Districts { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Foreman")]
    public string ClientForeman { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Zone")]
    public string ClientZone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Run")]
    public string ClientRun { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "API Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{14}|\d{2}-?\d{3}-?\d{5}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$", ErrorMessage = "A valid 14 digit API number is required.")]
    public string APINumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sample Point Name")]
    public string SamplePointName
    {
        get { return LeaseName + " " + WellNumber; }
    }

    //Foreign key
    [Display(Name = "Chemical")]
    public int? ChemicalId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChemicalId")]
    public virtual Chemical Chemicals { get; set; }
}
```

**2)** IdentityModels class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public static ApplicationUser Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationUser();
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set;  }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string InitialedName { get; set; }
    public bool HasChangedPassword { get; set; }

    //Foreign Key
    public int Employer { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employer")]
    public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<LabSample> LabSamples { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SampleLocation> SampleLocations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Chemical> Chemicals { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LegitDomain> Domains { get; set; }
    public DbSet<District> Districts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AccountManagerAssignment> AccountManagerAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

**3)** Chemical class:

```
public class Chemical
{
    [Key]
    public int ChemicalId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double ProductFactor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SampleLocation> SampleLocations { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because when you are attempting to delete the record from your Chemical table, one or more records in the SampleLocation table still reference it.

You have to first change the values of all records in the SampleLocation table that reference the Chemical record that you wish to delete. Once that is done, and no more records in SampleLocation are referencing the record in the Chemical table, you should be able to delete it.

Comment: Ah. So, in my delete method in the controller, I could first do a search for all records in the SampleLocation table where the ChemicalId exists in the ChemicalId column, and explicitly set those values to null, then proceed with my delete operation. I suppose that should work and get me moving again. I wonder though if there isn't a more elegant way, like instead of setting up the database to do a cascading delete(which would delete records that should _not_ be deleted,) if I could do a kind of "cascadingSetToNull" for that one parameter in the affected records?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a cascading delete, but yes you've got the gist of it now. You cannot have any foreign key fields referencing the original record in the primary table when you try to delete that record. That is precisely what a foreign key constraint is supposed to prevent.

Comment: So I modified the delete method in my controller and it works just fine now. Still feels wrong to me, like I'm breaking some rule, but it certainly works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code that worked for me is below. Thanks again, Kevin.

```
    // POST: LabData/ChemicalDelete/5
    [Authorize(Roles = "canDeleteDbAdmin")]
    [HttpPost, ActionName("ChemicalDelete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteChemicalConfirmed(int id)
    {
        foreach (SampleLocation l in db.SampleLocations)
        {
            if (l.ChemicalId == id)
            {
                l.ChemicalId = null;
                db.Entry(l).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        Chemical c = db.Chemicals.Find(id);
        db.Chemicals.Remove(c);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ChemicalList");
    }
```